# Virtual network interfaces starting on boot even though they are set to onboot=no , what could be the reason?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, centos6.5

I've re-installed my main database server with CentOS 6.5 .
I've configured the relevant NIC's including 3 virtual interfaces, called em2:0, em2:1 and em4:0.
For some unknown reason the NetworkManager daemon was not installed by the default installation (I chose "SQL Server").
Here are the configuration files for the virtual network interfaces:
`ifcfg-em2:0`:

```
DEVICE="em2:0"
ONBOOT=no
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.1.2.20
PREFIX=24
NN_CONTROLLED=no
```

`ifcfg-em2:1`:

```
DEVICE="em2:1"
ONBOOT=no
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.1.2.2
PREFIX=24
NN_CONTROLLED=no
```

`ifcfg-em4:0`:

```
DEVICE="em4:0"
ONBOOT=no
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.1.10.20
PREFIX=24
NN_CONTROLLED=no
```

Before I realized that NetworkManager daemon is not installed I've added `NN_CONTROLLED=no` to each one of the configs.
The problem is that after `reboot` or after `/etc/init.d/network restart` the virtual interfaces are turned on automatically even though they are configured not to start.
In addition, I've created a `route-em1` file in order to add a route to our OpenVPN network but after `reboot` or `service network restart` the `route-em1` file is being ignored because the route is not added automatically and I have to run it manually.
Do you have an idea why the system behaves like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected behavior.

You can see from "sysconfig.txt"

```
ONBOOT=yes|no (not valid for alias devices; use ONPARENT)
```

Now, why to use ONPARENT, because of this stanza down the same file:

```
Alias specific items:
    ONPARENT=yes|no
      Whether to bring up the device when the parent device is brought
      up.
      Default: yes
```

So even if you have "ONBOOT=no" "ONPARENT=yes" will prevail and activate your virtual interfaces.

Comment: Could you please where I can find the document?

Comment: [dladner@server.sec1 ~]$ cat /usr/share/doc/initscripts-9.03.40/sysconfig.txt | grep -E 'ONBOOT.*ONPARENT'
    ONBOOT=yes|no (not valid for alias devices; use ONPARENT)